# SWI-Prolog: Write predicate union(A,B,C) in form C = A ∪ B

Tags: prolog, predicate

Is their some way in SWI-Prolog to write predicates with three variables for example `union(A,B,C)` in the following form `C = A ∪ B`. For predicates with two variables I know their are operators to do that, but I am not sure if their is something similar in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Not directly. Prolog only supports defining unary operators (prefix/suffix operators such as `-- 32` or `32 ++`, both of which correspond to `'--'/1` or `'++'/1`) and infix operators (e.g. `X is Y` which corresponds to `is/2`).

If you look at the operator definitions and precedences, you would need to define your union operator as an infix operator with a precedence of less than 700.

Then, reading a term like `x = y ∪ z` would yield `'='( x , '∪'(y,z) )`.

Another way to do it would be to write a [DCG](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG) (definite clause grammar) to parse the text as desired. See this tutorial: https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg